# Divide and Conquer vs Backtracking

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, backtracking, divide-and-conquer, coin-change

Let’s use as an example the problem [LeetCode 322. Coin Change](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/)

I know it is best solved by using Dynamic Programming, but I want to focus on my Brute Force solution:

```
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
        curr_min = float('inf')

        def helper(amount):
            nonlocal curr_min
        
            if amount < 0:
                return float('inf')
        
            if amount == 0:
                return 0
        
            for coin in coins:
                curr_min = min(curr_min, helper(amount-coin) + 1)
            
            return curr_min
            
    ans = helper(amount)
    return -1 if ans == float('inf') else ans
```

The Recursion Tree looks like: [Recursion Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHMID.jpg)

I can say it is Divide and Conquer: We are dividing the problem into smaller sub-problems, solving individually and using those individual results to construct the result for the original problem.

I can also say it is Backtracking: we are enumerating all combinations of coin frequencies which satisfy the constraints.

I know both are implemented via Recursion, but I would like to know which paradigm my Brute Force solution belongs to: Divide and Conquer or Backtracking.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, under Backtracking it says "It is often the most convenient technique for parsing, for the knapsack problem and other combinatorial optimization problems.". Coin Change being an Unbounded Knapsack type problem.

Comment: @worbel: But then you have articles saying the brute force is a Divide and Conquer, like [0/1 Knapsack Problem](https://www.guru99.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming.html). The Internet is full of articles from both points of views. At this point, I am just tempted to conclude two options: 1) it belongs to none, and just call it recursion. 2) it belongs to both, and still just call it recursion to avoid confusion

Comment: If the implementation is categorized as recursion, it still can technically be in backtracking or divide and conquer, why be specific if not required :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complication in categorizing your algorithm is that there aren’t clear, well-defined boundaries between different classes of algorithms and different people might have slightly different definitions in mind.

For example, *generally speaking*, divide-and-conquer algorithms involve breaking the problem apart into non-overlapping subproblems. (See, for example, mergesort, quicksort, binary search, closest pair of points, etc.) In that sense, your algorithm doesn’t nicely map onto the divide-and-conquer paradigm, since the subproblems you’re considering involve some degree of overlap in the subproblems they solve. (Then again, not all divide-and-conquer algorithms have this property. See, for example, stoogesort.)

Similarly, backtracking algorithms usually, but not always, work by committing to a decision, recursively searching to see whether a solution exists given that decision, then unwinding the choice if it turns out not to lead to a solution. Your algorithm doesn’t have this property, since it explores all options and then takes the best. (When I teach intro programming, I usually classify algorithms this way. But my colleagues sometimes describe what you’re doing as backtracking!)

I would classify your algorithm as belonging to a different family of *exhaustive search*. The algorithm you’ve proposed essentially works by enumerating all possible ways of making change, then returning the one that uses the fewest coins. Exhaustive search algorithms are ones that work by trying all possible options and returning the best, and I think that’s the best way of classifying your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

To me this doesn't fit with either paradigm.

Backtracking to me is associated with reaching a point where the candidate cannot be further developed, but here we develop it to it's end, infinity, and we don't throw it away, we use it in comparisons.

Divide and conquer I associate with a division into a relatively small number of candidate groups (the classic example is two, like binary search). To call each path in a recursion a group for the sake of Divide and Conquer would lose the latter's meaning.

Comment: So it belongs to both, or it belongs to none. Hence my confusion. I am inclining to just call the brute force approach "recursion" and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical answer is it **doesn't matter**.
Safest answer **recursion**. My best interpretation is that its **backtracking**.

I think the options here are *recursion*, *backtracking*, *divide-and-conquer*, and *dynamic programming*.

Recursion being the most general and encapsulating of backtracking, D&C, and DP. If indeed it has backtracking and D&C algorithms then **recursion** would be the best answer as it contains both.

In Skiena's ADM (Section 5.3.1), it says:

> A typical divide-and-conquer algorithm breaks a given problem into *a* smaller pieces, each of which is of size *n/b*.

By this interpretation is doesn't meet the as we divide our solution by `coins` and each coin amount being a different size.

In Erickson's Algorithms (section 1.6), it says:

> divide and conquer:
>
> 1. **Divide** the given instance of the problem into several ***independent smaller*** instances of exactly the same problem.

So in this case, according to the recursion tree, are not always independent (they overlap).

Which leaves **backtracking**. Erickson defines the 'recursive strategy' as:

> A backtracking algorithm tries to construct a solution to a computational problem incrementally, one small piece at a time.

Which seems general enough to fit all DP problems under it. The provided code can be said it backtracks when a solution path fails.

Additionally, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking):

> It is often the most convenient technique for parsing, for the knapsack problem and other combinatorial optimization problems.

Coin Change being an Unbounded Knapsack type problem, then it fits into the description of backtracking.